# Can't add specific items to activity_main.xml

Tags: android, kotlin, dependencies

Android newbie here. I don't know why but I can't add specific items/elements to the activity_main.xml (NestedScrollView, CardViev, Google MapView, etc). If I try to add, let's say Google MapView, a message appears that says this :

This operation requires the library com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:+.

Problem: Inconsistencies in the existing project dependencies found.
Version incompatibility between:
-   com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0
and:
-   androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0

With the dependency:
-   org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5
versus:
-   org.mockito:mockito-core:2.19.0

The project may not compile after adding this library.
Would you like to add it anyway?.

Does anybody know what seems to be the problem? Build.gradle is displayed below.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 25
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
}
```

Comment: You should avoid passing `+` as the version. It will likely cause you a lot of issues if it one day updates without you noticing.

Answer (score 0):

The first of your problems is that you try to use Views, items, constants, etc, of a library that does not exist in your project, with these implementations it is more than enough for you to move forward, the problem with mockito is that you possibly implemented two versions and maybe the first version uses discontinued components, and therefore. Gradle will always look for the latest version, however both libraries need to live together, I recommend that you remove mockito 1.9.5 and try to synchronize again, I hope it was helpful , good luck!

`apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
dependencies{
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework:10.0.1'
}`